# What are the request per seconds of the AWS API Queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ec2, boto3

What are the **request per seconds** and average response times(roundtrip) of the following API calls made by Boto-2.38/Boto3 ?

```
    conn=EC2(aws_access_key,aws_secret_key_id)

    Q1:images=conn.get_all_images(owners=['self'])  
    Q2:instances=conn.get_only_instances()
    Q3:snapshots=conn.get_all_snapshots(owner='self')
    Q4:snapshot=conn.create_snapshot(volume_id, description)
    Q5:instance=conn.launch_instance(<params>)
    Q6:image=conn.create_image(instance_id,name,description)
    Q7:conn.deregister_image(image_id=image_id)
    Q8:volumes=conn.get_all_volumes()
```

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on many variables, so there is no one answer. Your latency to AWS, the size of the datasets you are requesting etc and if you are requesting often enough to get API throttled.

Your question implies an extremely heavy API use case so you need to check that your use case will really work in Amazon as they will throttle your api calls if you make too many. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-api-troubleshooting.html#api-request-rate